# Will redirecting 403 errors back to the homepage adversely affect bandwidth caused by webcrawlers?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I apologize if this isn't the right place to ask this and appreciate any help in moving it to a more appropriate forum if necessary.  My original question was going to be along the lines of what I need to do in the PHP to change this behavior... but I'm not sure if it's really the problem or not so this is a pre-question of sorts to find out whether I even need to bother asking the programming question that I was going to ask.

We have a site that's using too much bandwidth.  I was told it's being caused by web crawlers so I checked at sure enough that seems to be the case.  One thing I noticed was that 403 errors were responsible for most of the traffic.  I didn't see how that was possible since I would expect a 403 error to just send a little bit of informational text, but when I tried purposefully going to a url that didn't exist it redirected me to the homepage.

So I'm assuming every time a non-existent link is hit by a web crawler that it's transferring everything on the homepage... and I wonder if the web crawler thinks this is a new starting point from which it needs to branch out to all the links on the homepage all over again since it was hammering the website for over 24 hours straight before it got taken down?

---

EDIT: Seems that I made a mistake as halfer pointed out.  I saw '403' and immediately thought of the wrong thing.  It's *is* 403 (forbidden access) that is the issue, so maybe that means someone is trying to hack into the website?

---

Comment: What are the user-agents on the web crawlers? Most web crawlers check for a robots.txt first, which you can identify a sitemap that should be followed from within, any bot that doesn't follow these rules should be blocked as they're not performing according to guidelines. Therefore, you should probably just block these bad bots from visitng your page. If that's not an option, redirect 403 requests to an error document that's a blank white page with just text, that will not adversely affect your bandwidth in a shared (reseller) hosting environment.

Comment: Your website should be returning 404 for non-existent pages; that will tell any crawler to ignore any content returned, and that the link it just visited does not belong in their index.

Comment: are your redirects actual redirects? you should serve 403 as a 403, so with an actual 403 header.

Comment: You may also have a rogue crawler - are the high levels of traffic from a small number of IPs? Block them, if so.

Comment: @halfer You're right... I read 403 and thought the wrong thing.  So maybe that means a bot is trying to hack the website?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to see what the ip address is.  The only tools I have for doing so are through cPanel which I'm still learning.

Comment: @Bvernon You likely have an icon that says "Raw Access Logs" These are the DOMLogs to your website which report a time stamp. IP address, User-Agent, Page Requested, and the status returned (200,403,404,500 etc)

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy.  Downloading 7zip now so I can open them up.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Are you aware of any programs to help analyze the logs?

Comment: @BVernon There are analyzers for the logs but in reality they're pretty self explanatory, the first column is the IP address, the 2nd column is the page requested and the cod returned, the 3rd column is the user-agent that is returned by the client. Generally it's a browser uA string, but it can also be the Robot's UA string or it can be something like PHP, Perl, Lib:WWW, C+, etc

Comment: You could also upload your DOMLogs to [http://pastebin.org](http://pastebin.org) and then show us the link and we can analyze them.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Looks like what I get in the log is the same as what I viewed through the cPanel... only shows todays data.  I really need to see data for a few days ago but it's looking like that's not possible.

Comment: You would have needed to enable Archiving of your logs for that to occur. At this point if you need logs for yesterday you'll need to reach out to your Host who likely has Logs for the last 72 hours.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Just enabled archiving.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @BVernon: a 403 means that your own site has refused to serve content in a particular case. It is not in itself an indication of whether a bot is hacking you, no. Trace a URL that raises this response back to some code, and see _why_ it is raising that 403. Perhaps a 404 would be a better response in some of these cases, and they may encourage this particular bot to desist. If you believe you should be serving 403 in these cases, consider an IP blocking strategy instead: highly excessive requests that raise this error get added to the blocklist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not confound 403 and 404 errors. 403 is for forbidden, 404 for page not found.

You must have a .htaccess file on the root your website with something like that (same thing for 404 errors) :

```
ErrorDocument 403  index.php
```

Change `index.php` to a static page you add, or a message :

```
ErrorDocument 403 "forbidden
```

Do you have a sitemap ? Most crawlers use it. Read [this interesting article](http://moz.com/blog/do-sitemaps-effect-crawlers) about it.

Check which crawlers make the more request, and if necessary block them by IP.